# missing name after . operator error needs fixing

Tags: javascript

I am getting this error on the error console and can't seem to figure it out, I tried taking out the quotes, moving them around but still can't solve the error which is `:` missing name after `.` operator. How can this error be fixed?

```
var counter = 0;
counter++;
    
result = '<span class="imagemsg'+counter+'">The file was uploaded successfully!</span><br/><br/>'; 

...

jQuery.ajax("deleteimage.php?imagefilename=" + image_file_name)
    .done(function(data) {
        $(".imagemsg".counter).html(data);
    });
```

Comment: It looks like you're confusing Javascript and PHP syntax. Is there any reason you're preceding a Javascript variable name with $? It is valid, but I think it's much less common, unless it has some specific meaning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `+` to concatenate strings, not `.`, which means addressing object's property in JavaScript and, understandably, requires a property name.